# Timing function for "Wheel of Fortune" style ticker

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, timer, roulette-wheel-selection

I'm trying to create a function that changes a label's text. I want it in a "Wheel of Fortune" style where the text changes really quickly at first but slows down over time, then stops at the final text. I have the text as strings in an array.

I'm guessing I would need an exponential function to do this but maths is not my strong point. Currently I'm trying:

```
- (void)timer {
   float time = 0.5;
   float increase = 0.05;
   for(int x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
      sleep(time);
      time = time + increase;
      NSLog(@"%f", time); //Log to show time of each iteration
   }
}
```

I don't need help linking it up with labels etc., I just need help to get the timing right.

Comment: If you want it to be exponential, you need to multiply by some number instead of adding. Multiplying by 1.1 will give you the same number for the second iteration, and 1.07 get to 1 at about the same time.